# Pre-80's sci-fi book about a radionucleonic man who can see and affect the electromagnetic spectrum, and teleport in stressful situations

Tags: story-identification, books

This is a sci-fi book I read as a child in the 1980's I think, though the book might have been from the 50'-60's from the language and syntax used.

It involves a man who discovers he can see and affect the electromagnetic spectrum, and teleport in stressful situations. I recall him being called a "radionucleonic man" by a future woman in the story.

Other thing I remember the character was given a a capsule which subliminally gave him coordinates to teleport into the future.

It is not [*The Star My Destination*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Stars_My_Destination) (1956) by Alfred Bester.

Comment: This is a duplicate: [Time War by Lin Carter](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90556/soldier-teleports-himself-out-of-a-tank-using-his-mind-discovers-hes-from-the/94349#94349), 1974, Dell Publishing.

Comment: @jhpace1 We don’t close story ID questions as dupes unless we have explicit confirmation from both OPs; in this case, neither OP has confirmed they were looking for *Time War*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As indicated by [jhpace1 above](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/43546/looking-for-a-sci-fi-story-i-read-long-ago-about-a-radionucleonic-man#comment267563_43546), this might be a duplication of the question at [Soldier teleports himself out of a tank using his mind; discovers he's from the future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/90556/soldier-teleports-himself-out-of-a-tank-using-his-mind-discovers-hes-from-the/94349#94349) where the answer was 
*[Time War](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/4945468-time-war)* (1974) by [Lin Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin_Carter). Cover from Dell Publishing:

[image: Book cover, man and woman facing a red planet]

> John Lux was an electronic scientist, a level-headed industrialist, an ordinary twentieth-century man--at least he thought he was an ordinary man
>   ...until he discovered he could teleport himself
>   ...until he discovered that forces 200,000 years beyond his time were trying to destroy him
>   ...until he discovered that civilization of the future was being pampered into extinction in a kindergarten world and he was the only man in all eternity who could save it.
>   *But until John discovered how to use his dormant neuro-radionic powers, he was a helpless pawn in a time war--and both he and the planet were doomed...*

As you can see, he can teleport himself. He's referred to as having "neuro-radionic powers", and he travels to the future. jhpace1's answer also describes the device being provided with coordinates to the future.

Comment: This is it! Time War! You have made my Christmas.