# Soldier teleports himself out of a tank using his mind; discovers he's from the future

Tags: story-identification, time-travel

I am looking for a book that I read many years ago as a teen. I think it was in the 1970's but the book could have been written earlier. It starts with a soldier in Korea in a tank that is hit by a shell, and he find himself miles away in a rice paddy having teleported himself there using his mind. Many years later he finds himself approach by a women who is trying to kill him and force him to teleport himself into the future where she is from. His car is run into the river, where he is drowning, and he places a small tube to his ear which gives him the coordinates to the future. He finds himself millions of years in the future outside a city where he fights the computer running the city to save mankind. He then teleports further into the future following the girl. Does anyone know the title of this book?

Answer (score 5):

[image]

"Time War" by [Lin Carter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lin_Carter), 1974, Dell Publishing.

> MAN AGAINST TIME
>   John Lux was an electronic scientist, a level-headed industrialist, an ordinary twentieth century man - at least he thought he was an ordinary man
>   ...until he discovered he could teleport himself
>   ...until he discovered that the forces 200,000 years beyond his time were trying to destroy him
>   ...until he discovered that civilization of the future was being pampered into extinction in a kindergarten world and he was the only man in all eternity who could save it.
>   *But until John Lux discovered how to use his dormant neuro-radionic powers, he was a helpless pawn in a time war - and both he and the planet were doomed...*

The Author's Note says "This book is an affectionate tribute to one of the great masters of science fiction, Mr. A. E. Van Vogt."

The protagonist is American, but he served as a "young tank commander in Korea".  After having materializations happen in front of him, such as free-floating guns shooting at him and cars trying to drive him off the road, the protagonist John Lux goes to meet a friend of his, a psychologist named Dr. Havering.  John is also visited by a woman, the Lady Lis, claiming to be from the future, who gives him the device that will transport him to the future, in an emergency.  John must shortly use the device after fleeing the Silver Men - autonomous shapeshifting robots from the future.

There are so many parallels to A.E. Van Vogt's "The World of Null-A", from the protagonist going to a psychologist to find out what is wrong with him, to a mysteriously exotic woman, to a Weapon Machine engaged in a 10,000-year war against Arthex the Living City ruled by a computer caught in a logic trap.  Our superman John Lux forces himself out of his self-made millionaire 1960s lifestyle into an unbeatable force against machine logic with fantastic weapons and bring about the Crisis Point of the Arcadian Age that the desperate time-travelers beg John to complete.

A good read, if you are a fan of 1940s-style SF and/or A.E. Van Vogt.